# How to run Firebase JS SDK on Java Desktop using Nashorn?

Tags: javascript, java, firebase, nashorn

The reason I'm trying to do so, I want to use firebase realtime database from desktop application written in java. But I can't use Admin SDK because it'll be used by end user and I don't want to provide service keys.

For now I can read and write data to firebase using Firebase RestAPI, but I'm not able to retrieve data as soon as it's available, need some functionality like "childEventListener". And I thought, maybe I can achieve this by running rest api through javascript engine. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("nashorn");
engine.eval(new FileReader("firebase-listener.js"));
```

and in firebase-listener.js

```
load("firebase.js");
var config = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "xxx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://xxx.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "xxx",
    storageBucket: "xxx.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "..."
};
var defaultApp = firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

And I'm getting

```
javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot read property "fetch" from 
undefined in firebase.js at line number 1
```

Stuck at this point. Or maybe it's not possible, or I'm searching in wrong way... If it's the case, please, point the right way or give some explanation why it's not possible / not correct way.

Comment: 0

Hi, I was considering the same approach. Did you manage to get any further?

Comment: @J.P. no. It was long ago, but as I remember, we just switched to use NativeScript